# Possibilities to accept input for COBOL batch program

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have a batch COBOL program which needs input in the form of a flat file. It is working when I FTP a single file to the batch using a software.

Problem is that , in the final solution , many concurrent users are needed to access the batch program together or individually. For example lets say 10 users need to run the batch.

- They can FTP all of the files to a shared directory from where the Mainframe can access the file.

Now the problem comes as to

- How the Mainframe Job can be triggered?
- since there will be 10 or more files , the JOB needs to run each one of them individually and generate a report.
- How should the file names be? for example if two files have same name they will get overridden when they are FTP into the shared directory in the first place. On the other hand if the file names are unique , Mainframe will not be able to differentiate between them .

The user will recieve the report through E-Mail its coded in the Batch program, the ID will be present in the input Flat file.

Previously the CICS functionality was done through excel macro(Screen scrapping). The whole point of this exercise is to eliminate the CICS usage to reduce MIPS

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How will your users retrieve the generated report?

Comment: @cschneid Through E-Mail.. its coded in the Batch program, the ID will be present in the input Flat file

Comment: Talk to your Production Control and Scheduling people. They will tell you how they want it done. If you do it "your own way" you'll run the risk of having to re-do it.

Comment: @BillWoodger Our production control is in its infantries, You tell them a job to run they will run it , its simple as that but, the issue the TAT for doing this.. The present solution is by using Excel macro and CICS screen which is instant.

Comment: As to no Production Control, that way lies chaos. Can you update the question to include how the Excel and CICS were previously used? Do you know what a GDG is? Do you have a Scheduler?

Comment: @BillWoodger Our scheduler is Control-M , This should be a "On-Demand" type of job not a scheduled one if that's your question.

Comment: Its kind of a round about way, but you could make an online program and have the user identify which input file they will be using, then dynamically create a JCL in the online program to run the batch job and submit it to the internal reader. Then, since the user identified the input file, you know the right one was picked up AND the job was run pretty much instantly.

Comment: http://www.bmc.com/it-solutions/control-m-advanced-file-transfer.html If you don't have that (I imagine it will cost) have you consulted the documentation/your Scheduler team to see if there is anything "non-advanced"?

Comment: ok , we are thinking or writing a program that will run continuously in the background to check availability of any file. and on top of that, a java program which passes files to the folder which the COBOL file is referring to .. Thanks for all of your help guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riffing off what @SaggingRufus said, if you have Control-M for scheduling you can use CTMAPI to set an auto-edit variable to the name of your file and then order a batch job.   You could do this via a web service in CICS using the SPOOLWRITE API to submit the job, or you could try FTPing to the JES spool.

@BillWoodger is absolutely correct, get your production scheduling folks and your security folks involved.  Don't roll your own architecture, use what your shop has decided is right for it.